# Login pelo facebook SDK

Tags: php, mysql

Bom recentemente fiz uma página de login onde tem o login normal e o por facebook, só que o login por facebook quando clica redireciona pro aplicativo pra permitir o acesso, ok até aí tudo bem, só que quando clica e permite ele retorna para a página com um código no navegador só que aí exibe a mensagem de erro Erro de conexão com Facebook O ID e Secret estão certos!

```
    <?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['code'])){

  // Informe o seu App ID abaixo
  $appId = '680167435480727';

  // Digite o App Secret do seu aplicativo abaixo:
  $appSecret = 'xxxxxxx';

  // Url informada no campo "Site URL"
  $redirectUri = urlencode('$path');

  // Obtém o código da query string
  $code = $_GET['code'];

  // Monta a url para obter o token de acesso e assim obter os dados do usuário
  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
  . "client_id=" . $appId . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirectUri
  . "&client_secret=" . $appSecret . "&code=" . $code;

  //pega os dados
  $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
  if($response){
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    if(isset($params['access_token']) && $params['access_token']){
      $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="
      . $params['access_token'];
      $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

    // nesse IF verificamos se veio os dados corretamente
       if(isset($user->email) && $user->email){

    /*
    *Apartir daqui, você já tem acesso aos dados usuario, podendo armazená-los
    *em sessão, cookie ou já pode inserir em seu banco de dados para efetuar
    *autenticação.
    *No meu caso, solicitei todos os dados abaixo e guardei em sessões.
    */

        $_SESSION['email'] = $user->email;
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $user->name;
        $_SESSION['uid_facebook'] = $user->id;

        $mail =  $_SESSION['email'];
        $name = $_SESSION['nome'];
        $name = $_SESSION['uid_facebook'];

        $check = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail = '$mail' LIMIT 1"));
        if($check==0){  

    // REGISTRO

    function GenerateName($mail){
    $name = current(explode('@', $mail));
    return $name;
}

        $username = GenerateName($mail); // Nombre generado
        $password = substr(md5(rand(0, 999). strtolower($mail). rand(0,100000)), 0, 12);    

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (username,real_name,password,auth_ticket,motto,mail,rank,look,gender,account_created,last_online,online,ip_last,ip_reg,working,secretcode,mymusik,home_room,vip) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."','Habbo','".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."','-/-','".$sitename." <3','".mysql_real_escape_string($mail)."','1','".$look."','".$gender."','".time()."','".time()."','1','".$remote_ip."','".$remote_ip."','','','','0','1')") or die(mysql_error());

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

        header('location: '.$path.'/welcome');
        exit();

        }else{

        // LOGIN
        $userq1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail = '$mail' LIMIT 1");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($userq1)){

        $credUser = $row['username'];
        $credPass = $row['password'];

        $_SESSION['username'] = $credUser;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $credPass;

        header('location: '.$path.'/me');

        }
        }
      }
    }else{
$login_fehler = "Ocorreu um erro de código. Contate-nos através de nosso facebook fb.com/HebbiBrasil";
      exit(0);
    }

  }else{
$login_fehler = "Ocorreu um erro de código. Contate-nos através de nosso facebook fb.com/HebbiBrasil";
    exit(0);
  }
}else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['error'])){
$login_fehler = "Ocorreu um erro de código. Contate-nos através de nosso facebook fb.com/HebbiBrasil";
}
?>
```

Comment: Recomendo que remova o App Secret da sua pergunta, visto que é algo secreto (como o nome já diz) e especifico pra sua aplicação. Sugiro que redefina-o também já que foi posto aqui.

Comment: Você baixou a biblioteca do Facebook?
Está relacionada com o arquivo atual?
Dá uma olhadinha aqui.
É o código mais atualizado atualmente na Internet para login com a SDK do Face. [http://www.krizna.com/general/login-with-facebook-using-php/](http://www.krizna.com/general/login-with-facebook-using-php/) Além de claro, estar totalmente comentada!
Olha aí e me fala.

Comment: Remova o "@" para não omitir erros, você quer saber o que está dando erro, não use o "@" para omiti-lo. Se estiver utilizando o `file_get_contents` você precisa permitir que ele se conecte com website externo, no caso [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) no `php.ini`

Comment: Não precisa do SDK, tudo é possível ser feito utilizando o cURL ou o `file_get_contents`/`fopen`, nativos do PHP, inclusive também está documentado em https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference todos os *endpoints* para serem utilizados.

Comment: Ah sim. Também é utilizada. Porém imaginei que mesmo ele utilizando file_get_contents($token_url);, houvesse algum diretório relacionado o qual não havia sido feito o link (require)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O serviço de **API Login Dialog** do **Facebook** é usada para requisitar dados de um usuário com o consentimento do mesmo.

Para usar o serviço precisa [criar um APP](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) para receber as credenciais.

Seguindo o modelo [FB.login v2.12 da documentação em Javascript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.12) iremos criar um exemplo funcional do **login via facebook**

Um botão com ID **fb-login** :

```
 <button class="btn btn-facebook" id="fb-login" type="button">Logar Usando o Facebook</button>
```

No Jquery

```
         var appId = '680167435480727';
          //Load the Facebook JS SDK
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement('script');
            js.id = id;
            js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: appId,
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v2.3',
                status: true,
                cookie: true
            });
        };
        function showDetails() {
            FB.api('/me', {fields: fields}, function (details) {
                // Imprime no HTML os dados do usuário
                //$('body').append(JSON.stringify(details, null, '\t'));
                try {
                    $.post('facebook.php', {"dados": details}, function (json) {
                        if (!json.error) { // ocorreu tudo certo
                            window.location.href = json.url;
                        } else {
                            console.log("Não foi possível logar");
                        }
                    }, "JSON");
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log("Erro ao logar via facebook");
                }
            });
        }
        // Tipos de permissão que irá ser pedida ao usuário.
        var permissions = [
            'email',
            'user_birthday'
        ].join(',');
        // Campos que vão ser retornados após o login ser confirmado
        var fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'first_name',
            'middle_name',
            'last_name',
            'birthday',
            'email'
        ].join(',');
        $('#fb-login').click(function () {
            fbAsyncInit();
            // Tenta fazer o login
            FB.login(function (response) {
                // Se usuário está logado ....
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    showDetails();
                }
            }, {scope: permissions});
        });
```

Se ocorrer tudo certo, a função irá fazer um **POST** dos **dados** recebidos em **facebook.php** :

```
   $graphObject = $_POST['dados'];
   if (empty($graphObject['first_name'])) 
       return print json_encode("error"=>1,"msg"=>'Não conseguimos extrair o seu nome');

   if (empty($graphObject['id'])) 
       return print json_encode("error"=>1,"msg"=>'Não conseguimos extrair o ID do seu perfil');

   if (empty($graphObject["email"])) 
      return print json_encode("error"=>1,"msg"=>'Não conseguimos extrair o email do seu perfil');

// a partir daqui continua sua função de login, já que todos os dados necessários foram enviados.
```